# Fragments backStack - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am using FragmentTabHost in my App to show 2 tabs (Tab1 and Tab2)

Tab1 - Home Fragment 
Tab2 - List View Fragment

OnItemselected on list , replace the listview fragment to the detail fragment inside the same tab (tab2)

And I'm using addBackstack to navigate to list View fragment .Everything works fine .

If i'm navigating to the other tab (tab1) from my detail fragment without going back to my listview fragment , Tab 1 works as expected but when come back to Tab2 , its empty (Supppose to show my listview fragment).

I don't know where i am wrong , please guide me .

Thanks

Regards
Muthu

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ListView fragment again when you're going to the First tab. And Replace the fragment inside the setOnTabChangedListener() with following way

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

static TabHost mytabs;

mytabs = getTabHost();

mytabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         

        Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mytabs.getCurrentTab());

    if(mytab.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
    ListViewFragment lFragment = new ListViewFragment();

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, lFragment); 
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        }
    }       
});
```

I hope this would help you.